# Iterating over a list and using a dictionary to extract the value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

I have been trying to solve this problem for hours and would appreciate some help! So I have a list and a dictionary to work with:

```
new_list = ['A', 'B', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'N', 'O', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Z'] 

grades_per_student = {'A': 80, 'B': 80, 'C': 84, 'D': 96, 'E': 75, 'F': 83, 'G': 74, 'H': 79, 'I': 60, 'J': 70, 'K': 68, 'L': 55, 'M': 88, 'N': 77, 'O': 80, 'P': 81, 'Q': 79, 'R': 60, 'S': 57, 'T': 72, 'U': 56, 'V': 77, 'W': 75, 'X': 75, 'Y': 97, 'Z': 73}
```

My job is to iterate over the `new_list` variable and print out the string and its corresponding integer by using the dictionary keys and values.

This is what I have tried:

```
for key,value in grades_per_student.items():
    new_list.append(value)
print(new_list)
```

when I run the code this is what I get:

```
['A', 'B', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'N', 'O', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Z', 80, 80, 84, 96, 75, 83, 74, 79, 60, 70, 68, 55, 88, 77, 80, 81, 79, 60, 57, 72, 56, 77, 75, 75, 97, 73]
```

It's close enough but I am attempting to get something like this: `['A':80, 'B':80, 'E':75, etc...]`. I also think I am iterating over the dictionary when I'm supposed to iterate over the list.

Comment: `['A':80,` is confusing because you can't have a `:` like that in your list you'd get a `SyntaxError`. Can you clarify why type of output you are looking for? Also how is your list `new_list` related to the `grades_per_student` dictionary? Your desired output just looks like a list version of your dict.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. These are the instructions verbatim: "iterate over the list of student names and print out their names and score (use the name as a key to access the value contained in the grades_per_student variable)". The "student names" refers to the strings and the score is the interger, so in ['A':80]  A is the student name and 80 is the student's score. Does this make sense now?

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating `grades_per_student` but you should iterate `new_list`:

```
for i in new_list:
    print(f'{i}: {grades_per_student[i]}')
```

Comment: Also, do you mind explaining what the f means?

Comment: That's just [string formatting](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#3-string-interpolation-f-strings-python-36). A shortcut to allow variables to be printed as strings. You could also do `print(i, grades_per_student[i])`, but f-string formatting is easier if you wish to include the colon. Without string formatting it would be `print(i + ': ' + str(grades_per_student[i]))` as you'd have to convert the integer to string manually.

Answer (score 0):

You are just appending the values to the end of the list with `new_list.append(value)`. Why do you want a list? Can't you just use the dict instead?

If you really want a list I would do something like this:

```
new_list = []
for key, value in grades_per_student.items(): 
    pair = str(key) + ":" + str(value)
    new_list.append(pair)
print(new_list)
```